# Makefile to Shell Conversion

Tags: bash, shell, makefile

1. Was trying to convert a basic Makefile into a shell equivalent and was getting lost in some basics.
2. Below is the piece of code in Makefile

   ```
   WHAT1_UC           := ALOHA 
   WHAT1_NUM          := 1 
   WHAT1_WHERELOG_VAR = $(WHAT1_UC)_WHERE_FILENAME
   ifeq ($(strip $(WHAT1_NUM)), 1)
     $(WHAT1_WHERELOG_VAR) = mac.@PATH@.log
   else
     $(WHAT1_WHERELOG_VAR) = $(RLDIR)/mac.@PATH@.t%.log
   endif
   export $(WHAT1_WHERELOG_VAR)
   ```

   Query:
   a. In this what does @PATH@.log represents ? Is it picking the default env variable PATH ?
   b. So what will be the final value of WHAT1_WHERELOG_VAR, is it export ALOHA_WHERE_FILENAME = mac.@PATH@.log ??
3. Below is the piece of shell code was trying based on the above Make code, but getting lost to replicate the equivalent of it.

```
WHAT1_UC="ALOHA"
WHAT1_NUM=1 
WHAT1_WHERELOG_VAR=${WHAT1_UC}_WHERE_FILENAME
if [ $WHAT1_NUM == 1 ]; then
  export ${WHAT1_WHERELOG_VAR}=mac@$PATH@.log
else
  export ${WHAT1_WHERELOG_VAR}=${RLDIR}/mac.@PATH@.t%.log
fi
```

What is the shell equivalent of @PATH@ to be used ??

Please clarify the above queries. Let me know what is getting missed ? Thanks.

Comment: Why? Trying to implement all the dependency checking will become very complicated.

Comment: What version of `make` are you using?  If that is some kind of variable references, it's definitely not something specified by POSIX and not anything I can find in the GNU `make` documentation.

Comment: @Barmar 
So leaving the @PATH@.log variable, in general how to add a variable export setup like how thats done in Make into shell ?

Comment: @chepner Not sure with the make version. Just an existing code wanted to try/convert into shell and its needed.

Comment: @Vimo I think your translation to the `export` command is correct.

Comment: @Barmar Its not working as expected. If I try to run, it print the value of WHAT1_WHERELOG_VAR as ALOHA_WHERE_FILENAME. I was expecting the command that will get executed to be
export ALOHA_WHERE_FILENAME=mac@PATH@.log but I don't see any variable called ALOHA_WHERE_FILENAME getting set.

Comment: How are you checking if it's being set? Unless you use `source` or `.` to run the script, it won't affect your current shell process. Environment variables are exported to child processes, not the parent processes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Query: a. In this what does @PATH@.log represents ?

In POSIX or GNU `make`, @PATH@.log represents @PATH@.log.  But the @PATH@ part might not have been intentional -- it has the appearance of a placeholder that was intended to have been filled in by a separate program, such as `autoconf`, as part of generating the makefile you're looking at.

Alternatively, it may be that that is intended to be subbed out during the build, instead.

> Is it picking the
> default env variable PATH ?

No, it has no special meaning in any dialect of makefile that I know.

> b. So what will be the final value of
> WHAT1_WHERELOG_VAR,

It is ALOHA_WHERE_FILENAME.

> is it export ALOHA_WHERE_FILENAME = mac.@PATH@.log
> ??

No. `$(WHAT1_WHERELOG_VAR)` and `${WHAT1_WHERELOG_VAR}` expand to the value of variable `WHAT1_WHERELOG_VAR`.  They have nothing to do with setting the value of that variable.

> What is the shell equivalent of @PATH@ to be used ??

It is `@PATH@`, which is no more meaningful to the shell than it is to `make`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But few queries:
1. The value of WHAT1_WHERELOG_VAR is ALOHA_WHERE_FILENAME which is fine.
2. But at the end when export is executed why the WHAT1_WHERELOG_VAR isnt getting replaced with ALOHA_WHERE_FILENAME ? I was expecting the final command to be 
export ALOHA_WHERE_FILENAME=mac.@PATH@.log but I don't see any variable getting set with ALOHA_WHERE_FILENAME.

Comment: @Vimo, I guess you're asking about why your Bash code doesn't do what the makefile does?  That would be because the shell doesn't use the same evaluation rules that `make` does.  In particular, the shell identifies variable assignments *before* variables are expanded.  You could perhaps get around that by using the `eval` command, whose argument(s) are expanded to form a command, then executed: `eval "${WHAT1_WHERELOG_VAR}='${RLDIR}/mac.@PATH@.t%.log'"`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comments. How do I export the output of the eval ?
Tried like eval ABC="${WHAT1_WHERELOG_VAR}='${RLDIR}/mac.@PATH@.t%.log'". When I tried echo $ABC was able to see the value as ALOHA_WHERE_FILENAME=mac@$PATH@.log, but then how to re-direct this to export ?
Tried like eval export ${WHAT1_WHERELOG_VAR}='${RLDIR}/mac.@PATH@.t%.log'", but wasn't working.

Comment: @Vimo, you do not export the *output* of the `eval`.  The `eval` executes its (expanded) arguments as a shell command.  The effect in this case will be to set a value for variable `ALOHA_WHERE_FILENAME`.  If you want to export that variable then do so.  I would recommend doing it via a separate `export` statement, much like your original makefile does.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs again... But do I need to re-direct the output of eval to another variable so that I can export it ? Or is there an option to export it directly ? I tried the above ways i.e. eval ABC = "" or export $(ALOHA_WHERE_FILENAME), but couldn't get it. Wondering how to export the output of eval.

Comment: What output of `eval`, @Vimo?  You seem not to be getting it: `eval` expands its arguments and then *executes* the result.  If the arguments expand to a variable assignment then the effect is to assign the specified value to the specified variable.  There is no output to capture or manipulate in that case.  I already gave you exactly the `eval` command to use.  Now, separately, `export` the variable.  Use `eval` again for that, if you wish.

Comment: Did understand that. My bad. Got it going. eval "export ${WHAT1_WHERELOG_VAR}" got it set. Thanks for your valuable inputs.